# How to Find out the Boot up Password in a laptop

Tags: bios, password-recovery

I have a friend who has his laptop locked by a boot up password. He has asked me how to view the password. Please note that he does not wish to reset it. Anyone has any idea of software etc. to do the same?

Comment: are you talking about a password on the BIOS, hard drive encryption, or the operating system?

Comment: password in BIOS. the password when the Lappy Boots up, that is the BIOS one, i guess.

Comment: what laptop model/make?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I do not know, its an old one, maybe compaq. Really have no idea about the make, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page details some useful information for recovery a lost BIOS password - http://www.pwcrack.com/bios.shtml

Answer (score 0):

CGsecurity has a [tool](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd) that works on older laptops, and some tips on other means of recovery. You might also be able to get the master bios password if you can find the service manual for the system somewhere on the internet.